# Siphon's tip got into the carboy

Tags: bottling, siphon

I am on the 10th day of fermentation, and tried to get a sample to measure gravity with siphon. However after a few pushes, it stopped working and I noticed that the tip got into the carboy, which I cannot recover I believe.
See the picture below
 [image]

What should I do now? I cannot wait for another siphon, it is a lame brand, broken on the first attempt. I have a bucket with spigot. I am considering to hold the carboy, and drop the batch inside to the sterilized, sanitized bucket. I have to do the dry hopping today, should I do hopping inside the bucket or inside the carboy?

Any risk here? If it is risky, how can I fix the damn siphon which I will never use again?

The beer tastes fantastic and I dont want to spoil it.

Picture of outer tube:

[image]

I have the following black part

[image]

But not the otherblack part, I guess which must be check valve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave it until the batch is done.

Your racking cane will still function, you just have to hold it above the trub.

The tip only functions as diverter when the cane is held on the bottom of the fermentor, so it doesn't make a seal when held down.

Update: use a paper towel soaked in sanitizer to make a seal. When held in place with firm pressure from your hand you can then blow into the air filter and create positive pressure in the carboy to get the siphon flowing.

[image]

But if your just trying to take a sample for now, I'd invest in a Turkey baster.

As far as why it came off, the outlet tube may have been kinked or closed somehow, so the downward plung created pressure to pop the end off. It should still function once you can reattach it. Just use care when using to avoid the issue again.

Comment: well it does not work. I put the bottom end to a carboy filled with water, and put the hose end to the outside bottle. It did not fill or pull any water. Carboy is 2 feet above the bottle.

Comment: @EmmetB there's a check valve that the tip attaches to if it's not held up from the bottom it may get held open, causing it not to function.

Comment: that tip is inside the carboy, I cannot get it. I updated the picture, the inner stick has a black tip, and that tip is wide open. Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: @EmmetB yes the plunger tube should have a hole. The outter tube end has a check valve so wort can't flow out the bottom once in.

Comment: I updated my post with the outer tube. That is what I have, I lost one black part, which is probably the check valve. Is that OK? I lost the check valve I think, my bad, I have the closing tip.

Comment: @EmmetB yep check valve and tip are missing. Attach a sanitary air filter to the end of your output hose and apply suction. Then pinch it off once the wort in the tube is a few inches below the wort level in the fermentor, remove the filter. You will then have siphon flow.

Comment: Added pic to show how to use positive pressure to get the siphon flowing, rather than suction. Either way work.

Comment: you mean suction through mouth?

Comment: @EmmetB yes, but you need either a very long secion of tube you can remove from the sanitary end or a sanitary air filter. It can be done without risk of infection. Using positive pressure has much less risk though.